# Mongoose - await is a reserved word

Tags: mongoose

I am using a static Model method and need a function within it to act synchronously. I installed the `babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator` npm package, but get the warning:

> await is a reserved word

Here is the static method:

```
SomeSchema.statics.doSomething = async function(data, callback) {
    ...
    this.model('Template').findById(id, function (err, doc) {
        let ref = await getNextSequence();
        ...
    });
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Needed `async` on the query callback too:

```
SomeSchema.statics.doSomething = async function(data, callback) {
    ...
    this.model('Template').findById(id, async function (err, doc) {
        let ref = await getNextSequence();
        ...
    });
    ...
};
```

Comment: Do you know whether `async` is required on *both* the wrapper function *and* the query callback - or *just* the query callback?   I am looking at this answer that says:   `In order to use await, the function *directly enclosing it* needs to be async`   https://stackoverflow.com/a/42299762