# Await is a reserved word error inside async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, redux

I am struggling to figure out the issue with the following syntax:

```
export const sendVerificationEmail = async () =>
  (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: EMAIL_FETCHING, payload: true });
      await Auth.sendEmailVerification();
      dispatch({ type: EMAIL_FETCHING, payload: false }))
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: EMAIL_FETCHING, payload: false });
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  };
```

I keep getting error saying:

> await is a reserved word

...but isn't it legal within an async function?

The dispatch bit is coming from the [**react-thunk**](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) library.

Comment: It's not inside an async function. It's inside the function that starts with `(dispatch) => `, and that's not async. Why do you have the `sendVerificationEmail` returning another function instead of carrying out some action?

Comment: @JLRishe indeed it needs to be `async (dispatch) =>` you could post that as an answer, I need to return it in order to get access to dispatch

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html

Answer (score 325, accepted):

In order to use `await`, the function directly enclosing it needs to be async. According to your comment, adding `async` to the inner function fixes your issue, so I'll post that here:

```
export const sendVerificationEmail = async () =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: EMAIL_FETCHING, payload: true });
      await Auth.sendEmailVerification();
      dispatch({ type: EMAIL_FETCHING, payload: false }))
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: EMAIL_FETCHING, payload: false });
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  };
```

Possibly, you could remove the `async` from the outer function because it does not contain any asynchronous operations, but that would depend on whether the caller of `sendVerificationEmail()` is expecting it to return a promise or not.

Comment: Indeed that outer async is not needed

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! I had the same problem inside a forEach... brutal :)

Comment: Ditto here for using await embedded in a forEach and then in an async function.

Answer (score 6):

## Solution

Use the `await` directly inside the scope you are using `async` and remove the top scope `async` as it's redundant.

**The correct way to write this:**

```
const sendVerificationEmail = () =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    await Auth.sendEmailVerification();
    // some code..
  };
```

## Elaboration

You had the error because you used the `await` keyword without the `async` directly in the scope with the `await`, you had 2 functions there, one inside the other, you had `async` on the top one but not on the inner one, where it matters.

Wrong way:

```
const sendVerificationEmail = async () =>
  // notice that an async before the (dispatch) is missing
  (dispatch) => {
    await Auth.sendEmailVerification();
    // some code..
  };
```

From this, an error will be generated (the latest error available from Chrome):

*`Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`*

## Reference

### [`Async Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> An async function is a function declared with the async keyword, and
> the await keyword is permitted within it. The async and await keywords
> enable asynchronous, promise-based behavior to be written in a cleaner
> style, avoiding the need to explicitly configure promise chains.