# How to use async await with React componentDidMount() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use `async/wait` with React `componentDidMount()` method but I am getting  **await is a reserved word** error. I also tried wrap the statement in Immediate Invoked Function but it didn't help.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this.geoLocation.getAddress().then(location => {
    if (location.address != null && location.error != "undefined") {
      let fifteenMins = [];
      await this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x).then(
        data => {
          fifteenMins = data["forecasts"];
        }
      );
        console.log(fifteenMins);
    } 
  });
}
```

If I remove the `await` keyword, then I get `null` in console.log, but if I do console log right before `fifteenMins = data["forecasts"];` then I get data.

Related question:
[Await is a reserved word error inside async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299594/await-is-a-reserved-word-error-inside-async-function)

Comment: what's your node version?

Comment: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/how-async-await-in-react/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`async` functions always return promises. Since `componentDidMount` isn't designed/documented as an `async` function, React doesn't do anything with the promise it returns. If you use an `async` function for this, be sure to wrap all its code in `try`/`catch` so that all errors are caught and you don't end up with an unhandled exception (which becomes an unhandled rejection).

The problem is that you're trying to use `await` in a non-`async` function: The callback you've passed `then`. When using `async`/`await`, you almost never use `then`. Instead:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const location = await this.geoLocation.getAddress();
    if (location.address != null && location.error != "undefined") {
      const data = await this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x);
      let fifteenMins = data["forecasts"];
      console.log(fifteenMins);
    } 
  } catch (err) {
      // Do something with the fact an error occurred
  }
}
```

Or avoiding returning a promise from `componentDidMount` by using an IIFE:

```
componentDidMount() {
  (async () => {
    const location = await this.geoLocation.getAddress();
    if (location.address != null && location.error != "undefined") {
      const data = await this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x);
      let fifteenMins = data["forecasts"];
      console.log(fifteenMins);
    } 
  })()
  .catch(error => {
    // Do something with the fact an error occurred
  });
}
```

Or don't use an `async` function at all (but `async` functions are really handy):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.geoLocation.getAddress()
    .then(location => {
      if (location.address != null && location.error != "undefined") {
        return this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x)
          .then(data => {
            let fifteenMins = data["forecasts"];
            console.log(fifteenMins);
          });
      } 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Do something with the fact an error occurred
    });
}
```

---

Side note: This pair of lines:

```
const data = await this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x);
let fifteenMins = data["forecasts"];
```

can be written like this if you like, destructuring the result into the `fifteenMins` variable:

```
let {fifteenMins: forecasts} = await this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x);
```

Similarly, if you did decide to go with the non-`async` version, you can do that in the parameter list of the `then` handler:

```
.then(({fifteenMins: forecasts}) => {
  console.log(fifteenMins);
});
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks

Comment: For the sake of future people who google into this. Correct me if I'm wrong but while it is true that the promise isn't used there's no harm in adding `async` to `componentDidMount()` to simply enable the use of async await without using a IFEE (aka it's less typing). 

The trade off is it might be a little less clear for newer developers reading the code for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using await you dont have to use then

```
let data=  await this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x);
```

edit

```
let location = await this.geoLocation.getAddress();
  //do your stuff
  if (location.address != null && location.error != "undefined") {
    let fifteenMins = [];
    let data = await this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x);
    fifteenMins = data["forecasts"];
      console.log(fifteenMins);
  }
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Which says, await is reserved word.

Comment: let location = await this.geoLocation.getAddress();
  //do your stuff
  if (location.address != null && location.error != "undefined") {
    let fifteenMins = [];
    let data = await this.getFifteenMinsData(y, x);
    fifteenMins = data["forecasts"];
      console.log(fifteenMins);
  }