# converting functions to async await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I'm in the process of converting some functions to async await and need help to solve an error.

Before

```
const getRequest = (url, headers) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(url, { headers })
            .then((res) => {
                return resolve(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
            return reject(err);
        });
});
```

After

```
async function getRequest(url, headers) {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url, { headers })
                return resolve(res);
            }
        catch(err){
                return reject(err);
            };
    };
};
```

I'm getting an error when running the new code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862338/how-to-use-async-await-with-react-componentdidmount-method/51862358?noredirect=1#comment90677059_51862358

Comment: What kind of error occurs?

Comment: `axios.get` is a already awaitable you do not need all that `new Promise` stuff

Comment: The error is due to syntax, there should be function inside promise

Comment: Why do you need the new promise? Axios will take care

Comment: Thanks for the votes, @IIeon would like to know the issue with my answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use async await with React componentDidMount() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862338/how-to-use-async-await-with-react-componentdidmount-method)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Answer (score 3):

```
async function getRequest(url, headers) {
    const res = await axios.get(url, { headers })
    return res;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your original code is badly indented, so let's fix that:

```
const getRequest = (url, headers) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(url, { headers })
            .then((res) => {
                return resolve(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return reject(err);
            });
});
```

Secondly, your original code contains a whole lot of unnecessary code because `axios.get` is already a promise. This shows lack of understanding on how promises work, please read [this list of anti-patterns](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html). You should just return the promise directly. Fixing that:

```
const getRequest = (url, headers) => {
    return axios.get(url, { headers });
});
```

Thirdly, converting a function to `async`, when the function already returns a promise, means nothing more than simply adding the `async` keyword itself. You do not have to do anything to the function. Final result:

```
const getRequest = async (url, headers) => {
    return axios.get(url, { headers });
});
```

Comment: @Roamer-1888 oops, you're right, of course, thanks for catching. Fixed. The anti-pattern is so bad that it twisted my mind :P

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have got a syntax error in declaring a promise.

The `getRequest` function should look something like this -

```
async function getRequest(url, headers) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url, { headers })
            return resolve(res);
        }
        catch (err) {
            return reject(err);
        };
    });
};
```

Second, id `axios.get(url, { headers })` is waiatable, you do not need to return a promise from the parent funtion.
You can simply return await axios.get(url, { headers });

```
async function getRequest(url, headers) {
    return await axios.get(url, { headers });
};
```

> Example

```js
async function parent() {
    console.log(await child(true));
}


function child(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!!data) {
            resolve("resolved!");
        } else {
            reject("rejected!");
        }
    });
}

parent();
```