# Getting an error "await is a reserved word", while running meteor a application

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm using Crypto2(https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto2) library for Public/Private key production . I'm producing these keys while registering some patient as in code below.

```
Template.patient_register.events({
  'submit form': function(event, template) {
      event.preventDefault();
     const {privateKey,publicKey} = await crypto2.createKeyPair();
      var _email           = event.target.registerEmail.value;
      var _password        = event.target.registerPassword.value;
      var _disease_group   = event.target.registerDisease_Group.value;
      var _account_type    = event.target.registerAccount_Type.value;
      var _publickey       =  await crypto2.readPublicKey('key.pub');

      console.log("Public Key Is:::"+_publickey);
      console.log("Private Key Is:::"+await crypto2.readPrivateKey('key.pem'));
      var newAccount = {
         email         :  _email,
         password      :  _password,
         disease_group :  _disease_group,
         account_type  :  _account_type,
         public_Key    :  _publickey
      };

      Accounts.createUser(newAccount, function(err) {
       if (err) {
       ....................

       } else {
        .....................
       }
      });

      template.find("form").reset();

   }
});
```

But when I run this code it fails with an error "await is a reserved word". Please help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Await is a reserved word error inside async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299594/await-is-a-reserved-word-error-inside-async-function)

Comment: Besides the await issue, I may be wrong, but it seems your trying to execute a server side npm method on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the **`async`** declatation to tell compiler that this function uses async functions and will have to `await` them :

```
'submit form': async function(event, template) {
```

Answer (score 1):

(Async/await) is always used in pair. Whenever you create a function which contains statement await it must be used in pair with async.

```
function add(x,y){
   return x+y;
} 

// if you do not write async you will be prompt with (SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function)

async function test(){
  const x = 1;
  const y = 2;
  const result = await add(x,y);
  console.log(result) // 3
}
```