# Read data from local .txt file and store it inside a variable

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a helper function(fetchData.js is the file name) which will send an array of json like this..

```
export const jsonData = async (file) => {
    const response = await fetch(file);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    return jsonData;
};
```

Now I want to utilize this helper in some other file ,

```
import { jsonData } from './fetchData.js';

jsonData('./data2.txt').then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

and Its showing data perfectly, absolutely no issue..!!

[image]

But if I do something like this,

```
import { jsonData } from './fetchData.js';

let returnedData;
jsonData('./data2.txt').then((data) => {
    returnedData = data;
});
console.log(returnedData);
```

it returns undefined..

[image]

How to do ?

Edit :

[image]

Comment: move the console.log inside the `then` just below the `returnedData = data;` All your operations with `returnedData` should be inside the `then`

Comment: then why should I use returneddata? cant't I do that with data also? That's not my point, I want to store data inside a local variable.

Comment: You have to wait the async `jsonData`. `console.log` seems to be executed before `returnedData` is set.

Comment: then use `async-await`, `let returnedData = await jsonData('./data2.txt')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to log inside the `then` block since `Promises` are asynchronous.

```
import { jsonData } from './fetchData.js';

let returnedData;
jsonData('./data2.txt')
.then((data) => {
    returnedData = data;
})
.then(() => console.log(returnedData));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `await`, because your `jsonData` is asynchronous:

```
let returnedData = await jsonData('./data2.txt');
```

Comment: If I do  that then I am getting an error , await is a reserved word

Comment: You `jsonData` is not async. Try to define it `async jsonData(file) {...}`

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299594/await-is-a-reserved-word-error-inside-async-function