# Making an api call for each value in an array in an async function

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous, use-effect

I have an array of id's and I am trying to iterate over that array to make an api call for each id present. However my api call doesnt seem to be going through can anyone provide some insight?

the array of id's looks something like this:
`["provider-e44f1ccd-839c-413b-9559-0d2b359ee541", "provider-1cd9c1fe-de26-4b44-a1b9-03e6fc103ac4", "provider-1cd9c1fe-de26-4b44-a1b9-03e6fc103ac4", "system", "system", "provider-1cd9c1fe-de26-4b44-a1b9-03e6fc103ac4"]`

my function to make the call looks like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loadProvider = async () => {
        
      if(entries.length > 0){
        const providerID = entries.map((entry => entry.createdBy))
        console.log(providerID)
        try{
            const results = await api.Providers.get(providerID[+i])
            console.log(results, "12345678987654321")
    }catch(err){}
      }
    };

   loadProvider();
  }, [entries]);
```

I am able to get inside the `try` statement but only one call is returned when i console `results`

I also tried using to `map` over `entries` inside the `try` statement but I got a syntax error for my `await`  result variable.

Comment: what is `i` ? `providerID[+i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`providerID` is an array. You would do well to rename it to something that reflects that. Like `providerIDs`, for example.

`providerID[+i]` is a syntax error.

If you want to make an API request for each id, you have to somehow *iterate* your `providerIDs` array. You can do that using a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const loadProvider = () => {
    const providerIDs = entries.map((entry) => entry.createdBy);
    providerIDs.forEach(async (id) => {
      try {
        const result = await api.Providers.get(id);
        console.log(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })
  };

  loadProvider();
}, [entries]);
```

Comment: I understand your solution but Ive tried it and it always gives me a syntax error this is the same reason i left the map outside of the try statement. The error says that `await is a reserved word`

Comment: Ah, it looks like that in order to use `await`, the function directly enclosing it needs to be `async`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299594/await-is-a-reserved-word-error-inside-async-function).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all and .map

```
let results = await Promise.all(entries.map(async (entry) => {
    try {
      const result = await api.Providers.get(entry.createdBy)

      return result;
    } catch(error) {
      //handle errors
    }
  }));
```

Comment: This also gives me the same error where it says `await is a reserved word`