# React JS Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am struggling with this async await issue I have created async function and for that I am calling await but I am getting error **Unexpected reserved word 'await'**
Below is the async function

```
export const addProductCall = async (product) => {
    let accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    await axios.post(SERVER_URI + '/inventoryservice/v1/item',
        product,
        { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken, "Content-Type": "application/json" } })
}
```

Below is the function from where I am calling this function.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
        const data = {
            'storeId': customerDetails.id, category, categoryToBeAdded, description,
            productCode, productName, sku, price, unit, quantity
        }
        await addProductCall(data);
    }
```

Comment: the second function is missing the async keyword before ()

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299594/await-is-a-reserved-word-error-inside-async-function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use the await keyword outside of an async function :

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  const data = {
    'storeId': customerDetails.id, category, categoryToBeAdded, description,
      productCode, productName, sku, price, unit, quantity
  }
  await addProductCall(data);
}
```

should be :

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const data = {
    'storeId': customerDetails.id, category, categoryToBeAdded, description,
      productCode, productName, sku, price, unit, quantity
  }
  await addProductCall(data);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
```

with

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
```

For `await` to work, it needs to be wrapped inside an async function