# How do I fix error: "Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (10:22)eslint"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

As per the title, I want to solve this error message:`"Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (10:22)eslint"`

This is my current, working code snippet:

```js
import { WebClient } from '@slack/web-api';
import { prSummaryBotEnvVariables } from '../pr-summary-bot-env/env-exported-variables.js';
import { getUsersFirstAndLastName, removeUndefinedValuesFromArray } from '../utils/utils.js';

const botToken = prSummaryBotEnvVariables();
const client = new WebClient(botToken.botUserOauthToken);
let slackUserEmails;

const client = new WebClient(botToken.botUserOauthToken);
let slackUserEmails;

try {
  const { members } = await client.users.list();
  slackUserEmails = members.map(member => member.profile.email);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}

const slackUserNames = removeUndefinedValuesFromArray(getUsersFirstAndLastName(slackUserEmails));

export { slackUserNames };
```

I'm just using [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list/code) to get all our members' usernames & do some manipulation with it before exporting the `array`. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42299762/9884190) with two inner `async` keywords, but it didn't work. How can I refactor this?

**Update:**

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791115/9884190), but I just get an empty `array`:

```js
import { WebClient } from '@slack/web-api';
import { prSummaryBotEnvVariables } from '../pr-summary-bot-env/env-exported-variables.js';
import { getUsersFirstAndLastName, removeUndefinedValuesFromArray } from '../utils/utils.js';

const botToken = prSummaryBotEnvVariables();
const client = new WebClient(botToken.botUserOauthToken);
let slackUserEmails;
const slackUserNames = [];

(async () => {
  try {
    const { members } = await client.users.list();
    slackUserEmails = members.map((member) => member.profile.email);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  slackUserNames.push(removeUndefinedValuesFromArray(getUsersFirstAndLastName(slackUserEmails)));
})();

console.log(slackUserNames); // empty array
export { slackUserNames };
```

Comment: For starters, you are using `await` outside an `async` method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679505/using-await-outside-of-an-async-function

Comment: @fjc I know what the issue is. I'm trying to get help with the refactoring.

Comment: @Phix tks, I have tried but no luck. I have updated my answer. Any ideas what's happening here with the refactoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot use the `await` keyword outside of `async` functions. For that same reason, you won't be able to export `slackUserNames` as a variable, as it depends on previously executing asynchronous code.

A straightforward approach would be to export an asynchronous function from your file that you could use in other parts of your project then:

```
import { WebClient } from '@slack/web-api';
import { prSummaryBotEnvVariables } from '../pr-summary-bot-env/env-exported-variables.js';
import { getUsersFirstAndLastName, removeUndefinedValuesFromArray } from '../utils/utils.js';
export async function getSlackUserNames() {

    const botToken = prSummaryBotEnvVariables();
    const client = new WebClient(botToken.botUserOauthToken);
    let slackUserEmails;

    const client = new WebClient(botToken.botUserOauthToken);
    let slackUserEmails;

    try {
        const {members} = await client.users.list();
        slackUserEmails = members.map(member => member.profile.email);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    const slackUserNames = removeUndefinedValuesFromArray(getUsersFirstAndLastName(slackUserEmails));

}
```

Now you could call this function somewhere else in your project:

```
const slackUserNames = await getSlackuserNames();
console.log("Slack users are: ", slackUserNames);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately, now I trade the warning from the `exported` file to the `imported` file where I'm calling `const slackUserNames = await getSlackuserNames();`

Comment: Use the same solution. You simply cannot use `await` outside `async` functions. Wrap your code in another `async` function.

Comment: I see, uffff that's my only option? I would rather not do it like so. Maybe refactoring to `new Promise` could help?

Comment: `async/await` is, technically, nothing else than wrapping things into `Promise.then` chains, just simpler and more readable. You will not escape having to wrap asynchronous code in either. Even if you export a `Promise` (which you can), to consume it, you'll need to use `async/await` again or `Promise.then`. `async/await` does the same thing, just leads to more readable code.

Comment: Alright man thanks for the answer!